# Как повесить событие на кастомный UISlider в Objective C?

Tags: slider, objective-c, события

Привет!

Есть такой код:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 20);
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

Как повесить на этот слайдер событие, например, для отслеживания `slider.value`?
Я так понял, что это делается через `addTarget`, но как правильно это сделать, так и не понял. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: UISlider наследник UIControl, читайте документацию о всех родительских классов, это открывает глаза на многие фичи.

Answer (score 2):

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//где-то среди методов self
-(void) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*) sender{
//обработка изменения
}
```

Вместо UIControlEventValueChanged может быть другое событие, это уже в справке посмотрите.